# Animate setStyle in Prototype?

Tags: animation, prototypejs

This is my code:

```
$$('.container ul')[0].setStyle({
  top: '20px'
});
```

Is there a way to animate that code in Prototype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add script.aculo.us to your page that will provide the animation you are looking for.

try using the `morph()` method which will tween between your current style and the style you pass

```
$$('.container ul')[0].morph({
  top: '20px'
});
```